# как открыть порт в Azure?

Tags: azure, vds, port

При деплое сервера, по умолчанию, в панели управления открыт порт для удаленного управления с такими настройками:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По аналогии добавил свой порт с такими настройками:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И по своему порту я не могу пробиться, фактически он закрытым и остался, в файрволе тоже открывал, я его уже и выключил совсем - ничего не помогает. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим? Возможно где-то в другом месте нужно что-то настроить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего не открыт "Endpoint". Открой найстройки машины --> Endpoints --> Add (кнопка сверху). Ну и туда надо добавить этот порт 1100.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это необходимо из-за устройства Azure. Открытие порта в файрволе машины не означает автоматическое открытие порта в Cloud Service. Cloud Service можно представить себе как некий свич висящий перед виртуальными машинами.

Answer (score 0):

А как это настроить в портале Azure? Там Endpoints в свойствах машины нету.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примерно такая же история, нужно открыть порт 8080. Добавил его в сетевую группу безопасности - не работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А 80-й порт доступен даже если его из разрешений удалить.

Answer (score 0):

`$ netstat -ant`
Проблема, если:
1) у вас нет listening у нужного порта
2) у нужного порта стоит 127.0.0.1 вместо 0.0.0.1